# Create Singelton class in swift?

Tags: swift

```
   class var sharedInstance:OAuthClass {

 dispatch_once(&Static.token, {
            Static.instance = OAuthClass ();
        });

        return Static.instance!;
    }

 How can i create Singelton class in Swift. i am using this code.
```

is it right?what would be the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go,

The laziest and easiest way to do it is storing the singleton as a global variable:

```
let _SingletonSharedInstance = Singleton()

class Singleton  {
    class var sharedInstance : Singleton {
        return _SingletonSharedInstance
    }
}
```

You can read the details, advantages and disadvantages of this approach [here](http://jmduke.com/posts/singletons-in-swift/) in detail.

Also, please read [Korey Hinton Blog](http://koreyhinton.com/blog/singleton-pattern-in-swift.html).